# How to check if JMX agent is working in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I have a Tomcat 8 instance. I'm trying to connect to it from JColsole. In order to do so I have added to the `setenv.bat` the following line:

```
CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=D:\Utils\Apache\Tomcat\conf\remote.users -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=D:\Utils\Apache\Tomcat\conf\remote.acl -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7777 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

and in those two files -- `remote.users` and `remote.acl` i  have defined user *test* with password *test* and the role *readwrite*.

However I cannot connect via JConsole (I tried using url `localhost:7777` and `service:jmx:rmi://localhost:7777`).

Further investigation showed, that I cannot even telnet to 7777.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, when Tomcat is running as a service on Windows, I don't need `setenv.bat`, I need to use `tomcat8w.exe` -- GUI toll for adding options